# SQL query for date and month with 3 letter of month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-03-10 05:57:39.629597 | 2022-06-03 05:57:39.629597 |
| 2010-04-06 05:57:39.629597 | 2022-05-20 05:57:39.629597 |

I am writing SQL query to get an output which includes 3 letters of month and date from start_date and comma-separated same for the end_date like

| time_period |
| --- |
| 10 Mar, 03 Jun |
| 06 Apr, 20 May |

so tried this

```sql
SUBSTRING( MONTHNAME(start_date), 1, 3)  as time_period
```

and got the output like this

| time_period |
| --- |
| Mar |
| Apr |

how can get desired output?

Comment: MySQL OR Microsoft SQL server? update the question and remove the undesired tag.

Comment: mysql is am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try to use `DAY` function to get number of `start_date` and `end_date` and then use `CONCAT` function to connect them.

```
SELECT CONCAT(LPAD(DAY(start_date), 2, '0'),' ',SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME(start_date), 1, 3),',',LPAD(DAY(end_date), 2, '0'),' ',SUBSTRING(MONTHNAME(end_date), 1, 3)) time_period
FROM t
```

Or we can try to use [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) with `%d` and `%b`

```
SELECT  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%d %b'),',',DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%d %b'))
FROM t
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fefbdf77e01b641f374373ea82442bd4)